# GIT commands are taking 40 seconds on "git credential-manager get" with a call to an ADDC that is not responding, how do I disable this?

Tags: git, active-directory

When users are on our corporate VPN they have 40 second delays in git calls (push/fetch/pull...) that having done a pcap are caused by calls to the ADDC timing out twice (20 seconds a piece). I am not sure what these calls are but they seem to be part of 'git credential-manager get':

```
14:18:45.904593 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: 'git credential-manager get'
14:19:32.073092 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Users/xxxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
14:19:32.075099 git.c:703               trace: exec: git-credential-manager get
```

I have disabled network verification as I thought that may be the cause but that didn't work either. Turning off GCM meant I had to add credentials every time, and storing usernames and passwords in plain text is not an option.

The calls to the DC seem to be an EPM call giving a port number to connect to:
[image]

And then calls that time out:[image]

Comment: Stack Overflow is really just for programming questions. You're better off asking on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com), which is for server-administration questions.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, I have asked it on there.